# Rotating spatial coordinates omits other data

Tags: r, rotation, spatial

I have a `data.frame`of spatial data (X,Y) with a third column of attribute data (Z) assigned to each spatial coordinate. I need to be able to manipulate the spatial coordinates by rotating them around a central point and then analyse them with the attribute attached. I'm able to rotate the coordinates, but I can't seem to carry the third column of data through the rotation process. i.e. I need to remove the third column of data from the `data.frame` to perform the spatial manipulation.

[Here's the sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zc7708phfjlj6ua/Sample.csv?dl=0)

And here's the code I have thus far

```
data<-read.csv("Sample.csv",head=T)
head(data)

#Omit the attribute data

a<-data[-3]

angle <- pi/8
M <- matrix( c(cos(angle), -sin(angle), sin(angle), cos(angle)), 2, 2 )

# FIRST ROTATION
b<-as.matrix(a) %*% M
colnames(b)<-c("X","Y")
b<-as.data.frame(b)

# SECOND ROTATION
c<-as.matrix(b) %*% M
colnames(c)<-c("X","Y")
c<-as.data.frame(c)

# THIRD ROTATION
d<-as.matrix(c) %*% M
colnames(d)<-c("X","Y")
d<-as.data.frame(d)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))

plot(a,col='red',pch=19,asp=1)
plot(b,col='blue',pch=19,asp=1)
plot(c,col='green',pch=19,asp=1)
plot(d,col='purple',pch=19,asp=1)
```

What I need to be able to do is manipulate the spatial data in the way I have done above, but also carry across the original attribute assigned to each point coordinate (Z).

I've tried

```
M <- matrix( c(cos(angle), -sin(angle), sin(angle), cos(angle),1,1), 2,3 )
b<-as.matrix(data) %*% M
```

but get the following error

> `Error in as.matrix(a) %*% M : non-conformable arguments`

I'm stuck. can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out. It was so obvious. Just add in the extra column after the manipulation.

```
b$Z<-data$Z
c$Z<-data$Z
d$Z<-data$Z
```